# How to measure rendering time in Motorola Symbol Pocketbrowser 2.22?

Tags: html, browser

I am familiair with tools like pagespeed, yslow, firebug, dynatrax.
Sadly they won't help me, because I need to measure it in a browser called PocketBrowser from Motorola (PB2.22) on a PDA(MC55)
So I need some custom plain javascript which can help me get very close to the actual rendering time of a page in that specific browser.
A normal browser is fast enough so I don't have any issues at all there, but in the pocketbrowser it's too slow.